# Point Cloud Library's multiple-inheritance with single inheritance restriction

Tags: c++, inheritance, crash, cloud, point

The C++ plugin API in which I work is bad enough without STL/exception handling but it also forbids multiple-inheritance.  In other words, I can build with it if I don't mind my plugin crashing the host application on startup or I can go single and it will crash on the first direct instance of multiple inheritance in PCL (of which there is only one instance in my plugin code, but that is all it takes one supposes, and, yes, it is a required instance).

I assume that any multiple inheritances used within the PCL libs are isolated (since they appear to use this feature often) but as soon as I use something with it directly - crash.

There seem to be very few options.  I can try to find another library for point cloud surface meshing with commercial usage licensing (ha!) or actually write a separate executable using PCL that is called from the plugin to do the work and pass the results back to the plugin (horrendous, platform dependent, and not an integrated solution).  This entire entreprise is becoming loathsome.  So much time and effort expended researching, preparing, learning, adjusting projects, carefully setting this up only to find that it won't work under these conditions.

If you have an alternative BSD library option to mention that would be great. If you think that I should go for a CL/DOS-based application to be launched to do the processing that would be great to hear arguments for as well.  I support both Windows and MacOS X.

Comment: PCL tag is for Printer Control Language, not Point Cloud Library. Retag with point-cloud-library

Comment: Oh, thanks.  Actually PCL is also Point Cloud Library (duh).  Acronyms are not owned or trademarked. Sorry.  Fixed.

Comment: no objections to you using the word PCL, unless you use it as a tag. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point-cloud-library. You should tag with point-cloud-library. It is kind of a shame the point cloud library people were silly enough to call their product PCL, when PCL for printers has been very much around for nearly 30 years. Anyway the PCL for printers people have claimed the tag on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Going the external executable route.  I can save the point cloud to the pcd format from the application, run the executable to load and process the file to output the results in obj format for the application to use.  It is still a horrid solution but at least it works.